# I cannot understand this sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

I just came across a sentence:

> When the default registry is used in a package-lock or shrinkwrap is has the special meaning of "the currently configured registry".

So by my current understanding:

- "When the default registry is used in a package-lock" is the first part
- "or shrinkwrap is (used)" is the second part

  - am I correct to say that the word "used" omitted?
- 'has the special meaning of "the currently configured registry"' is the last part

  - am I correct to say that this is usd to describe (first part + second part)?

Comment: I imagine "is has" is a typo for "it has". It may not be your typo, but I think it is one. See if it's more understandable that way. I don't know what the other specialist terms mean.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty: Thanks for your help. I think your idea makes sense for me, it's a typo(I copy-paste the sentence) from the docs.